# How to store created POST request ID value to be used in a different method

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, post

I'm trying to use the ID for a created Order as the OrderId for OrderLine I need to create right after.

The Order gets created and if I console.log the orderId **INSIDE THE SUBSCRIBE METHOD** it displays the correct value.

But as soon as the subscribe function gets completed, the value reverts back to undefined.

The checkout method works

```
 async checkout() {
    // Perfom PayPal or Stripe checkout process
    this.createOrder();
    let alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: 'Thanks for your Order!',
      message: 'We will deliver your food as soon as possible',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present().then(() => {
      this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
    });   

    this.cart = []; 
     
    this.cartService.removeCartItemCount(); 
  }
```

The createOrder works (except for storing the orderId for reuse)

```
createOrder(){
    const orderForCreation: OrderForCreation = {
      orderDateCreated: this.currentDate,
      orderDateCompleted: this.currentDate,
      qrCodeSeatingIdFk: 2
    };

    const apiUrlOrder = 'api/order';
    
    this.repository.create(apiUrlOrder,orderForCreation)
      .subscribe( res =>{
        this.createdOrderId = res.orderId; 
        console.log(this.createdOrderId) //this works    
        this.createOrderLine(this.createdOrderId) //this does not work   
    }); 
    console.log(this.createdOrderId); //this does not
  }
```

The createOrderLine also works, but I do not know how to set the orderId to the correct Id

```
 createOrderLine(id){
    const apiUrlOLine = 'api/orderLine';
    for (let i = 0; i< this.cart.length; i++){
      const orderLineForCreation: OrderLineForCreation = {
        orderIdFk : id, //This isn't updating
      itemQty : this.cart[i].menuItemAmount,
      itemComments : "item comment",
      menuItemIdFk : this.cart[i].menuItemId,
      specialIdFk : 1,
      employeeIdFk : 1,
      }
      

      console.log('orderline not created');

      this.repository.create(apiUrlOLine, orderLineForCreation)
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.createdOrderLineId = res.orderLineId;
          console.log('OrderLineCreated');
        });
    }
  }
```

If anyone can tell me how to fix this issue it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscription to your *this.repository.create* is asynchronous, given that your are subscribing to an observable. You can not know when the subscription will be completed, and the log may be called before it is completed.

```
this.createOrderLine(this.createdOrderId) //this does not work
```

Here do you mean that the method is not called, or that the *this.createdOrderId* is undefined?

If you want the orderId to be returned from the *createOrder*, you must return an *Observable* from the *createOrder*, and subscribe to the observable in the checkout.

In the *createOrder*:

```
return this.repository.create(apiUrlOrder,orderForCreation)
  .pipe(
    tap(res => this.createOrderLine(res.orderId))
    map(res => res.orderId)
  );
```

In the *checkout*:

```
this.createOrder().subscribe(orderId => {
  //show alert etc.
});
```

There may be an issue in your existing code though in that your *this.createOrderLine* is being called, and the *createOrder* is returned before the items are finished being created - I'm not sure that's what you want. You could add all the items to an array of observables and do a forkJoin, then subscribe to the result.

Comment: Thank you, the `.pipe` part fixed my issue